# Forward requests coming into port 80, for a particular link, to port 8080 locally

Tags: glassfish, port-80

I have 2 web forms, one coded using Java Servlets on glassfish (port 8080) and another using PHP on apache(port 80). But my office ITdept is refusing to open port 8080 to outside traffic. How do I set up Apache such that requests coming in for the form with the servlets are directed to port 8080? Thanks TX PS: Im using wamp

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to use mod_proxy on apache...

Something like the following on your virtual host:

```
ProxyPass /somepath http://localhost:8080/SomeApp/somepath
ProxyPassReverse /somepath http://localhost:8080/SomeApp/somepath
```

This would make it so that when you access /somepath on your apache you're actually accessing the glassfish server /SomeApp/somepath.

You might need to add some more directives if you want cookies to be rewritten, etc... but the basic functionality is there...

More info on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html.

Not exactly sure how to set things up with wamp tho but I suppose there's an apache config file somewhere...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the better option would be to have IT NAT traffic for a specific IP from port 80 to 8080 onto whichever firewall is above your server?

Also, why will they not open this port?

Comment: They go on about security issues and stuff, those guys are really dumb, I dont want to deal with them. Also, if I dont find a good enough method of directing the traffic myself, Ill have to rewrite everything in the servlet into PHP..